# why my text is not visible when applying opacity to element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, flexbox

I am applying `opacity` to lighten my `background-color` due to this my `text` is not visible. Any way to increase the visibility ?

```
.abc{
  width:200px;
  height:200px;
  border:1px solid red;
  background: #211E1C;
  opacity: 0.03;
  color:green
}
```

here is my code

https://jsbin.com/tihowuveda/2/edit?html,css,js,output

In above example `ansn` text is not visible why ?

Comment: Because the opacity is 0.03! Do you realize that it is the opacity of the whole element?

Comment: Leave the opacity at 1 so that the contents remain visible, and only brighten your background: `background: rgba(33, 30, 28, 0.03);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Opacity is applied to the whole element so anything in it will have that opacity. You can use rgba to set the opacity of the background color.

```css
.abc, .foo{
  display: inline-block;
  width:200px;
  height:200px;
  border:1px solid red;
  background: #211E1C;
  color:green
}

.abc {
  opacity: 0.03;
}

.foo {
  background-color: rgba(33, 30, 28, 0.03);
}
```

```html
<div class="abc">Hello World</div>
<div class="foo">Hello World</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It is working as intended. Very low opacity means that it is barely visible or almost invisible.

Try setting 0.3 or something.

Reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/opacity

Answer (score 0):

`opacity: 0.03` is almost `opacity: 0`. that's why your text is hidden.

Please make the background value with `rgba`

```css
.abc{
  width:200px;
  height:200px;
  border:1px solid red;
  background: rgba(33, 30, 28, 0.03);
  color:green
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  
  <div class="abc">
    ansn
  </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

when you apply opacity to anything you are applying it to all the children element as well if you want to apply opacity to only background then try using alpha i.e. rgba colors have a look https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_image_transparency.asp